# AWS ELB application shows IIS server page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a .NET web application that is deployed to EC2 instances via AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I have auto-scaling enabled with instance counts ranging from 3-10.  I have notifications in place that tell me when new instances are added and no-longer-needed instances are removed from the cluster.

Sometimes, around when the instances are added/removed, I'm getting complaints from my users that they are seeing the IIS web server web page - you know, the blue one...?  After a few seconds, the same user is able to see the application correctly and things work fine.

I've turned off sticky sessions and I've enabled connection draining - what could be causing this?

Comment: How is your health check setup?

Answer (score 2):

Turning off sticky sessions wouldn't help this situation, and might actually exacerbate the problem to some extent. However the root of the problem is that your ELB health check appears to only be checking that IIS is responding, where it needs to be checking that your application is fully deployed and IIS is serving the application.

Configure your Elastic Load Balancer's health check to check for a page that will only be available once your application is fully deployed and running. Then a new server will not be added to the load balancer's pool (and users won't be routed to that server) until the application is being served properly on that server.

Comment: OK, I think you are correct.  I think that the LB is allowing traffic to the application before it's fully deployed.  So, I created a simple route at /health that just returns success.  However, when I save that the LB goes to "red".  I think it is because my application forces HTTPS and the LB is seeing that as "down".  True??  How can I make the LB health check use HTTPS?